# Pascal, 3 rows, only reads the first one, how to make it read the other 2?

Tags: pascal

```
program tekstinis;
var
  txt: Text;
  i, n: Integer;
  a, b, c: Integer;

function did: Integer;
begin
  if (a >= b) and (a >= c) then
    Writeln('Didziausias skaicius :', a)
  else
  if (b >= a) and (b >= c) then
    Writeln('Didziausias skaicius :', b)
  else
  if (c >= a)  and (c >= b) then
    Writeln('Didziausias skaicius:', c);
end;

begin
  Assign(txt, 'D:\Desktop\tekstine_rinkmena.txt');
  Reset(txt);
  Read(txt, a, b, c);
  if (a >= b) and (a >= c) then
    Writeln ('Didziausias skaicius :', a)
  else
  if (b >= a) and (b >= c) then
    Writeln('Didziausias skaicius :', b)
  else
  if (c >= a)  and (c >= b) then
    Writeln ('Didziausias skaicius:', c);
  ReadLn;
  Close(txt);
end.
```

This program's input is a text file with 3 rows containing 3 numbers. It reads the first row and shows the biggest number, but I don't know how to force it to read the other two rows.

EDIT:  forgot to mention that there are 3 rows with 3 numbers 
5 7 4, 
9 9 8,
8 7 8, 
I want the program to use every row in the if function. So then it could write the biggest number of each row ( so far i succeeded with the first row)

Answer (score 1):

After the 'reset (txt)' line, you will have to add a loop:

```
for i:= 1 to 3 do
 begin
  readln (txt, a, b, c);
  did;
 end;

readln
```

end;

Either you have the comparisons in the body of the main program or you have them in a separate procedure ('did'), but not both! For reasons of clarity, I have used the procedural version above.

Comment: This is a very static solution. When your file contains more than 3 lines, you will miss the rest. When your file contains less than 3 lines it even crashes! Always use the function eof(filename)

Answer (score 0):

Procedure `Read` read value only from 1 row in file. You need to use procedure `ReadLn`, which read value from file and go to next line.

More information here:

http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/read.html

http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/readln.html

So, your code should look something like this:

```
      Assign(txt, 'D:\Desktop\tekstine_rinkmena.txt');
      Reset(txt);

      ReadLn(txt, a);
      ReadLn(txt, b);
      ReadLn(txt, c);

      // ...

      Close(txt);
```

**EDIT:**

I can't check my code because I haven't pascal compiler. But I think that this code can help you:

```
Assign(txt, 'D:\Desktop\tekstine_rinkmena.txt');
Reset(txt);

While not Eof(txt)
Begin
  Read(txt, a, b, c);

  // your check of variables "a", "b" and "c"

  ReadLn(txt); // This should move file stream to the next string    
end;

Close(txt);
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that there are 3 rows with 3 numbers
5 7 4
9 9 8
8 7 8
I want the program to use every row in the if function. So then it could write the biggest number of each row ( so far i succeeded with the first row)